# Ocultar direccion de envio en woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Tengo implementado este codigo en woocommerce el cual esta testeado y funciona correctamente.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_order_needs_shipping_address', 'local_pickup_hide_shipping_address', 10, 3 );
function local_pickup_hide_shipping_address( $needs_address, $hide, $order ) {
    // Define below the shipping method slug that hides shipping address
    $shipping_method_id = '1'; 

    // Loop through shipping methods for the current order
    foreach ( $order->get_shipping_methods() as $shipping_method ) {
        if( $shipping_method->get_method_id() === $shipping_method_id ) {
            $needs_address = false; // Hide
            break; // Stop the loop
        }
    }
    return $needs_address;
}
```

Como se puede ver el codigo fallaria si el metodo de envio es distinto de 1. ¿ Como se puede hacer para que funcione siempre con independencia del tipo de envio? , con cualquier id .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo lo haría con

```
add_filter('woocommerce_order_needs_shipping_address', 'local_pickup_hide_shipping_address', 10, 3 );
function local_pickup_hide_shipping_address( $needs_address, $hide, $order ) {
    // Define below the shipping method slug that hides shipping address
    $shippings_array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; 

    // Loop through shipping methods for the current order
    foreach ( $order->get_shipping_methods() as $shipping_method ) {
        if (in_array($shipping_method->get_method_id(), $shippings_array)) {
            $needs_address = false; // Hide
            break; // Stop the loop
        }
    }
    return $needs_address;
}
```

Básicamente es, si el método de envío se encuentra en mi array, que lo oculte.

Comment: Hola si es una opción, h atener en cuenta. Gracias

Comment: Si te funciona recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada.

Comment: Pero se me acaba de ocurrir lo siguiente, y si se pone como que sea distinto a 0. Incluiría a todo lo demás no?

Comment: Como lo hagas y te funcione es algo que decides tu. Yo solo respondí a tu duda basado en tu propio código. Salu2...

Comment: Queria agradecerte la idea que me has dado, he podido comprobar que funciona tu codigo. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Ya sabes, para eso estamos...